# drag and drop game only two end results, right or wrong AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have been banging away on this issue for a long time now and I would love someone to whack me upside the head.  I feel like I am so close, but you know how that is.

I have a drag and drop game, 8 options and 5 are correct.  I want the user to drag 5 items from the 8 to the right of the screen.  When they reach 5, it gives them a result.  Right or Wrong (to keep the process moving I am not making them keep re-trying).  Well, at this point in my code, everything is working well, except, when the end comes it only shows the right answer no matter what they drag.  Please help.

I hope this is clear, thanks for any advice.  I already appreciate you if you even read this.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var cor_mc:correct_items_mc = new correct_items_mc;
var nopeAnswers:incorrect_items = new incorrect_items;
var policies:Array = [policy_0,policy_1,policy_2,policy_3, policy_4,policy_5,policy_6, policy_7];
var correct_choices:Array = [0,2,4,5,6];

var selected_items:Array = [];

for (var i:int = 0; i < policies.length; i++) {
    var mc:MovieClip = policies[i];

    mc.buttonMode = true;
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);
    mc.home_x = mc.x;
    mc.home_y = mc.y;
    mc.is_correct = correct_choices.indexOf(i);
}

function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.startDrag();
    setChildIndex(MovieClip(event.currentTarget), numChildren - 1);
}

function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var dropIndex:int = policies.indexOf(event.currentTarget);
    var target:MovieClip = event.currentTarget as MovieClip;
    target.stopDrag();

    if (target.hitTestObject(bucket_mc)) {
        selected_items.push(target);
        trace(selected_items);
        target.x = bucket_mc.x;
        target.y = bucket_mc.y + selected_items.length * 60;
    } else { // no match ... false
        target.x = target.home_x;
        target.y = target.home_y;
    }

    if (selected_items.length === correct_choices.length) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < correct_choices.length; i ++)
        {
            var cur_choice = correct_choices[i];
            if (!selected_items.indexOf(cur_choice)) {
                addChild(nopeAnswers);
                nopeAnswers.x = 0;
                nopeAnswers.y = 100;
            } else {
                addChild(cor_mc);
                cor_mc.x = 0;
                cor_mc.y = 100;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the Manual indexOf returns -1 if the element is not found. Does that really evaluate to false in actionScript 3 or is it being evaluated as true as it returns a value? In which case your (!...) condition would always evaluate as false and the nopeAnswer would never be triggered?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If well formatted, the code pretty much has everything - selected items, correct items.. You can easily check which is correct and which is not. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Manual [indexOf](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf%28%29) returns -1 if the element is not found rather than a boolean false.

Change the condition to:

```
if (selected_items.indexOf(cur_choice) < 0){
   ....
}
```

Also if any of your first 4 correct values have NOT been selected you still continue looping and so will still output cor_mc if the final correct item was selected. You need to stop the loop once you find a correct answer missing:

```
if (selected_items.indexOf(cur_choice) < 0) {
      addChild(nopeAnswers);
      nopeAnswers.x = 0;
      nopeAnswers.y = 100;
      break;
} else {
      addChild(cor_mc);
      cor_mc.x = 0;
      cor_mc.y = 100;
}
```

Comment: Pf, just now I saw the mistake.. Great eye! ;)

Comment: oops, I should have scrolled, further down!  Amazing.  Thank you so much.  Except now, it doesn't fire the correct answer part, only incorrect.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but you're also looping through each of the 5 - so you'll display the Nope/Yep Answer for each item - since it's in the same position each time I'm guessing you're only seeing the last answer (ie. whether the 5th item is correct or not) - if that's right you need to move the answer portion out of the checking loop

Comment: I am probably explaining it poorly.  When the fifth piece is dropped into the bucket, I want to make sure that their answers are the right 5, if they are correct, I want them to see the cor_mc.  If even one is wrong, I want them to see the nopeAnswers.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I guess what I am attempting to do, and admittedly this is over my skill set, is trying to make it compare the array correct_choices with selected_items, regardless of order.  If they are the same 5 then fore the correct answer.  If they are not the same five, then fire the incorrect answer.

Comment: Firstly, you're amazing for helping me with this, thanks.  Unfortunately, this is still only giving me the nopeAnswers response.

Comment: Can you check what is actually contained in selected_items array and post the output?

Add trace(selected_items[i]); to your for loop

Comment: in the trace function I built in, it just says [object MovieClip].  If I export those for AS and then name them so the right ones match the corrects_choices array it should work?

Comment: No, if you read the manual I linked in my answer you'll notice indexOf uses strict equality === comparison - so the items in your arrays also need to have the same types. Your selected items are MovieClip Objects, your correct choices are not...

Comment: ah gotcha, sorry I missed the link.  I just started using stack overflow today.  I will read this over and figure out how to rectify this.  I have used up enough of your time at this point.  Thank you.

Comment: perfect, you did it.  this part: var correct_choices:Array = [0,2,4,5,6]; needed to be var correct_choices:Array = [policy_0, policy_2, policy_4, policy_5, policy_6];